# Gatling. Certificate Authority. After certificate confirmation - SSLException Received fatal alert: unknown_ca

Tags: performance, load-testing, gatling

I need just a tip to know is that good or what to do to eliminate it.

You, I started recorder with self-signed Certificate | HTTP Proxy. Then via Firefox, I started Proxy and put
in a search this address https://mywebsite.com. It requested certificate (how Gatling's documentation writes: https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/http/recorder/)
I confirmed certificate adding and then it has opened my website, but in log (on the screenshots, I attached) appearing these
htttp detectportal.firefox GET requests and after my desired website it has added additional objects: 443/(2 screenshot) and other symbols (1 screenshot)

Could you tell me what's wrong, or it is ok? and I merely need to eliminate it in a scenario?

In the Terminal is apearing this:

> 15:25:05.971 [ERROR] i.g.r.h.h.u.HttpsUserHandler - Exception caught
>   on user channel [id: 0x947cbcb4, L:/127.0.0.1:8000 -
>   R:/127.0.0.1:49513]: SSLException Received fatal alert: unknown_ca 
>   [ERROR] i.g.r.h.h.u.HttpsUserHandler - Exception caught on user
>   channel [id: 0x0c0811a3, L:/127.0.0.1:8000 ! R:/127.0.0.1:57656]:
>   SSLException fatal SSLEngine condition

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNP29.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GhUO.png)